# PHP - HTML and CSS3 to PDF (and mPDF VS DOMpdf)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pdf

I've played with a lot of php html to pdf converters and got really sick of it. I liked the most DOMpdf with which I've worked for 2 months. Yesterday I tested mPDF, it was basically the same but much faster.

The problem is that I have an HTML file with internal CSS and external images, and if I use the advanced stuff, things like float, overflow, round-corners, shadows etc, then things just fall apart. Is there ANY way just to convert HTML and CSS into PDFs without any hassle and for free?

I don't even care how anymore. It can be JavaScript conversion. It can be an external site conversion, it can even be some kind of software (if that is possible in my hosting), a browser plugin (Not CutePDF, I need costum height adn width controls), a plugin for any CMS. **as long as it's not over complicated and I don't have to waste time on re engineering the design**

Any solutions for any kind of design with HTML + CSS so that I don't have to *censored* around with the design?

Comment: did you try it using mpdf as well? mpdf is great and supports almost all the tags..

Comment: yes. I've mentioned mPDF. I know it's great, but I had some design problems with it. I just don't want to hassle with the design and simply convert it

Comment: I tried other pdf generator apis, they didn't support all the css tags so I had to move to mpdf as it had what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this older post while looking for something else. But have you tried simply putting your HTML file onto google Drive, saving it as a Google 'doc', and then using the 'File->Save As->PDF ?  It works fine for me. You'll end up with your original HTML file, a Google Doc version, and a PDF version. There might even be an API for this now, I don't know.